# Traversing thru multiple layers of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my data

```
data = [
    {
        "title": "Main Topic 1",
        "num": "Type 1",
        "text": "Some Text",
        "sub": [
            {
                "title": "Sub Topic 1",
                "num": "1",
                "text": "Some more Text",
                "sub": [
                    {
                        "num": "(a)",
                        "text": "This is the actual text for the topic 1(a)",
                    },
                    {
                        "num": "(b)",
                        "text": "This is the actual text for the topic 1(b)",
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                "title": "Sub Topic 2",
                "num": "2",
                "text": "This is the actual text for the topic 2",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        "title": "Main Topic 2",
        "num": "Type 2",
        "text": "Some Text",
        "sub": [
            {
                "title": "Sub Topic 3",
                "num": "3",
                "text": "Some more Text",
                "sub": [
                    {
                        "num": "(a)",
                        "text": "This is the actual text for the topic 3(a)",
                    },
                    {
                        "num": "(b)",
                        "text": "This is the actual text for the topic 3(b)",
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                "title": "Sub Topic 4",
                "num": "4",
                "text": "This is the actual text for the topic 4",
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

Now, I want an output like this:

```
{'title': 'Main Topic 1~Sub Topic 1~NA', 'num': 'Type 1~1~(a)', 'text': 'This is the actual text for the topic 1(a)'}
{'title': 'Main Topic 1~Sub Topic 1~NA', 'num': 'Type 1~1~(b)', 'text': 'This is the actual text for the topic 1(b)'}
{'title': 'Main Topic 1~Sub Topic 2', 'num': 'Type 1~2', 'text': 'This is the actual text for the topic 2'}
{'title': 'Main Topic 2~Sub Topic 3~NA', 'num': 'Type 2~3~(a)', 'text': 'This is the actual text for the topic 3(a)'}
{'title': 'Main Topic 2~Sub Topic 3~NA', 'num': 'Type 2~3~(b)', 'text': 'This is the actual text for the topic 3(b)'}
{'title': 'Main Topic 2~Sub Topic 4', 'num': 'Type 2~4', 'text': 'This is the actual text for the topic 4'}
```

Here is my code to achieve that:

```
def get_each_provision(title, num, text):
    provision = {}
    provision['title'] = title
    provision['num'] = num
    provision['text'] = text
    return provision


def get_consolidated_provisions(data):
    provisions = []
    for level1 in data:

        title_level1 = level1['title']
        num_level1 = level1['num']
        text_level1 = level1['text']

        if 'sub' in level1:

            level2_subs = level1['sub']
            for level2 in level2_subs:

                title_level2 = '%s~%s'%(title_level1, level2['title'])
                num_level2 = '%s~%s'%(num_level1, level2['num'])
                text_level2 = level2['text']

                if 'sub' in level2:

                    level3_subs = level2['sub']
                    for level3 in level3_subs:

                        title = '%s~%s'%(title_level2, level3.get('title', 'NA'))
                        num = '%s~%s'%(num_level2, level3['num'])
                        text = level3['text']
                        provisions.append(get_each_provision(title, num, text))

                else:
                    provisions.append(get_each_provision(title_level2, num_level2, text_level2))

        else:
            provisions.append(get_each_provision(title_level1, num_level1, text_level1))

    return provisions

print('----------------------------------------------')
provisions = get_consolidated_provisions(data)
for each_provision in provisions:
    print(each_provision)
```

It works fine as expected. What I am trying to achieve is - basically get the lowest level of 'text' from each dictionary and sub-dictionaries (under key 'sub') My problem is two folds though:
(1) Is there a better way to achieve this? and (2) My code will break if there is another level of list of dictionary. I can apply another level but was hoping not to.

If you were wondering, the above variable "data" is a json format achieved by extracting a pdf file. The data extraction was successful, as shown in the variable 'data'. The idea is to identify each subsection and its leading sequence of 'num' and 'title'.

Point to be noted: (1) Lowest level will not have the key 'title' and (2) Lowest level of dictionary will not have the key 'sub'. Both as as shown in the variable data.

Comment: You can use `somedict.get('somekey', some_default) to avoid KeyErrror but, this makes traversing nested dicts just a little less annoying

Comment: I hate this problem so, some time ago, I created a class that makes possible to traverse such objects easier and that returns None if you fetched an invalid/undefined path, take a look https://gist.github.com/dhilst/121fe0d963e7e9c8c4402eb4e0863b2f

Answer (score 1):

You should use recursion to accomplish 'flattening' this list of dictionaries.

```
def flatten(items):
    new_list = []
    for i in items:
        if "sub" in i:
            new_dict = {}
            for k, v in i.items():
                if not k == "sub":
                    new_dict[k] = v
            new_list.append(new_dict)
            new_list += flatten(i["sub"])
        else:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list
```

```
# I've tested this with your data
flatten(data)
```

Comment: Recursion is definitely the best solution for situations where the data is finite!

Comment: I agree, Recursion was on my mind. Problem is - I lose track of the sequence. For example, I do not know what is the leading level of {'num': '(a)', 'text': 'This is the actual text for the topic 1(a)'}. I was hoping I'd know it belongs under title 'Main Topic 1','Sub Topic 1' and the num = 'Type 1/1/(a)'